# Ошибка получения времни timestamp из utcnow python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, utc

Хочу получить timestamp из utcnow, но timestamp() возвращает значение utcnow - 5 часов. Как мне получить timestamp по гринвичу?

Comment: это ваш случай? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573873/python-datetime-utcnow-returning-incorrect-datetime

Comment: @Zhihar Летнее время ну никак не могло внести погрешность в 5 часов.

Comment: Попробовал варианты `print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp());
print(time.time());
print(datetime.datetime(*time.gmtime()[:6]).timestamp())` - все вернули время в UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Правильный вариант:

```
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
```